# B-TREE и HASH индексы

Tags: sql, mysql

Привет. Интересует что такое `B-TREE`, `HASH` индексы? Как они влияют на ускорение выборки? Каков их синтаксис?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

B-tree он же balanced tree индекс, это индекс сгруппированный по листьям сбалансированного дерева. Применяется для больших индексов, по сути это индекс индексов. Ну скажем индексы с величиной от 1 до 10 хранятся в одной ветке, от 11 до 20 в другой и т.д., когда приходит запрос на индекс с номером 35, идем к 3-й ветке и находим там 5-й элемент. В общем как то так. Подробнее [здесь](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)

Hash индекс применяется для сравнения/построения индексов строчных и/или двоичных данных. Каждому значению индексируемого выражения сопоставляется значение определенной хэш функции отображающей исходное значение на целое число (иногда на строку). Подробнее [здесь](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)

B-Tree индекс дает скорость выборки порядка log(N), hash дает линейную. В реальной жизни hash и B-Tree применяются совместно, то есть для вычисления значений B-Tree индекса все равно применяются хэши.

Comment: > B-tree он же binary tree индекс

Это неверно. B - balanced - здесь означает сбалансированное, другими словами, каждый лист дерева имеет одинаковое число предков. В результате доступ к любым данным при помощи такого индекса осущствляется за одинаковое число шагов.

Comment: Благодарен за ссылки..

Comment: @Barmaley  а почему hash даёт линейную скорость? Я-то по простоте душевной считал, что там должно быть O(1), ежели коллизии не учитывать.

Comment: @alexlz да ты прав. Линейная скорость индексации, а скорость поиска конечно же постоянная

Answer (score 12):

Пусть у вас есть таблица

```
goods ( id int primary key,
        catalog_id int,
        sales_from datetime,
        sales_till datetime )
```

Если у вас Engine InnoDb или MyISAM, то первичный индекс только BTREE,
если тип таблицы MEMORY, то первичный индекс по умолчанию HASH, но можно назначить и BTREE. Для типа ndb - можно использовать как BTREE, так и   HASH

Если у вас частые запросы, типа:

```
   SELECT * FROM goods WHERE catalog_id = ...
```

то имеет смысл сделать индекс HASH по полю catalog_id

Если вы хотите найти товары, на которые в данный момент существуют скидки, т.е. условие:

```
WHERE sales_from > NOW() AND sales_till < NOW()
```

то тут однозначно надо использовать индекс BTREE

Comment: +1 за такой важный пример реального использования разных типов хранения индексов.